# RadPHP, Xcode, Phonegap and Cordova Problems

Tags: php, xcode, cordova, radphp

Briefly, (as briefly as possible) here's my scenario:

I have just gotten a trial of RADPHP XE2 and created a simple interface for a single page iPad app. I have exported the PHP design through PhoneGap and moved the resulting Xcode files to one of my Mac Minis. I have PhoneGap and Cordova installed on my Mac. Two problems occur which leave me dead in the water:

1. When I copy the PhoneGap bin file to the terminal app and use .create, I do not get the results I expect. Instead, I get an error message showing me the usage for the cp command. (??)
2. If I try to open the project file exported from RADPHP, Xcode will not open, saying that it is an invalid project file.

I am currently running on the latest version of OSX Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.4.1, and iOS 5.1.

Any advice or insights?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you download the required version of Cordova to install it in your Mac OS X system. See [this page of the RadPHP XE2 documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RadPHP/en/IOS_Setup), which includes a download link for **Cordova 1.3.0**.